# Nutch 2.X - Prefered urls to fetch

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I have this situation: There are over 160 URLs in my seed. I started my crawling one week ago. Now I have a lot of pages crawled in my storage but I can see in my Solr index that some URLs from seed are not crawled at all (the URLs do not have some restrictions from a robots.txt) or only in very small number. Is it possible tell Nutch to prefer some URLs?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked `TopN` value?
Or is Nutch still crawling? because indexing and sending data to solr is done at the end of process!

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is that some of URLs have for example 1500 indexed documents in Solr and some urls only 15, 20... and lot of them just 0 docs. I don't know why... it is not because of robotx.txt or some ban...

Comment: check TopN!
I think its limited! set it to -1!